# Reset google colab for every new user

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am creating an assignment where I have written a few Python functions as below in google colab. I expect every student to click on this collab link and fill out those functions. As this is an assignment, even if one student completes and saves it should get saved in the main collab file. How do I achieve this? Should I lock the cells so that they can copy this file on their Google Drive and edit it or is there any other way?

```
def add(a,b)
"""To Do """
```

Thanks,
Xi

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you do not want your students to make any changes in the original colab notebook?  You want them to do their work in their own copies of the notebook?

Comment: yes, that is correct if they are able to copy the notebook in their drive, even if someone posts a solution it won't be visible to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your students "viewer-only" permissions to your notebook.

Click on the "Share" link in the top-right corner of the Colab screen:

[image: Share button screenshot]

Then you can list the e-mail addresses of your students in the "Share with people and groups" box and select "Viewer" in the drop-down next to each address.

When they receive the link to the notebook and edit it, they will not be able to save their changes in that notebook.  They will get a message like this:

[image: save copy screenshot]

Hope this helps.